# SQL and FOREIGN KEY, REFERENCES

Tags: mysql, sql

Hello i have a problem to create table. I would like to create table with refferences to "Model"

```
CREATE TABLE Marka(
id_marki INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL ,
nazwa VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL ,
id_modelu int
FOREIGN KEY(id_modelu) REFERENCES Model(id_modelu) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

Model is simple table with id and name.
When i clicked to run it i got this error:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FOREIGN KEY(id_modelu) REFERENCES Model(id_modelu) ON DELETE CASCADE ) ENGINE=I' at line 5

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

You're missing a comma after `id_modelu int`

```
CREATE TABLE Marka
(
  id_marki INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  nazwa VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
  id_modelu int,
  FOREIGN KEY(id_modelu) REFERENCES Model(id_modelu) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you missing a comma after int?